# python package with pyproject.toml not availble when installing in editble mode

Tags: python, pip, pep517

i have a package (lets call it test-package) that has a pyproject.toml file but also has setup.py

if i install it locally with `python -m pip install -e . --no-use-pep517` with pip>=20.1.3,  the package is installed.`python -c "import inspect, test_package; print(inspect.getfile(test_package))"` works and points to local file

if i `python -m pip install -e .`  in a virtual env, `python -c "import inspect, test_package; print(inspect.getfile(test_package))"` works

if i `python -m pip install --no-build-isolation -e .` `python -c "import inspect, test_package; print(inspect.getfile(test_package))"` works

but `python -m pip install -e .` is successful, yet `python -c "import inspect, test_package; print(inspect.getfile(test_package))"`  results in an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_package'`.

I tried reading pep517 and pep518. i still don't understand how to reason about above behavior. i was wondering if someone can please explain to me

Comment: Which versions of setuptools and pip? What are the contents of `pyproject.toml` and `setup.py`?